# sql procedure import error

Tags: php, mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
drop procedure IF EXISTS `simpleproc`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `simpleproc`(OUT param1 INT)
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am trying to import the above code using PHP but I'm getting this error:

> Error performing query '':You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ drop procedure IF EXISTS `simpleproc`$$ CREATE PROCEDURE `simplepro' at line 1

Comment: Did you write this code yourself or did you just copy it from somewhere?

Comment: this code is in a sql file i want to import it into mysql

Answer (score 0):

The above syntax can only be executable at `MySQL` *command line* client.
The same won't work using server side scripting language.

Instead you can use the following as a string to construct the `query` and pass to `mysqli->query`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT )
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
END;
```

***Note***:
If you have only a single statement to be processed and executed in a stored procedure,
you don't even need `begin` - `end` blocks.

This is correct:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT )
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
```

Comment: Ravinder thanks for your reply but even simple query like `DELIMITER $$
Drop procedure IF EXISTS simpleproc $$
DELIMITER ;` is not getting imported.

Comment: i am using a simple line of code like `$commands = file_get_contents($filename);
mysql_query($commands)`

Comment: It is a set of statements but not a single. I don't think we can execute multiple statements in mysql using php on a single call.

Comment: Instead you try the `DROP ...` statement directly from php and it should be working.

Comment: I did try that ravinder but no luck `DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS simpleproc$$
DELIMITER ;`

Comment: Excluding `Delimiter` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your procedure syntax, please use following

```
DELIMITER $$;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `simpleproc`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `simpleproc` (OUT param1 INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
END$$

DELIMITER ;$$
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: @vivek can you please tell me what is the error as i have run this in my local DB and it worked fine.

Comment: yes it is working directly when i put it in mysql but not through php.

Comment: @vivek Setting the delimiter to something other than `;` by `DELIMITER $$` is *not* an sql command; it's a mysql shell command. If you're trying to define a stored proc though php (not sure why you would do this, or even if it's possible), you'll have to figure out how to change the line delimiter using php's db api, so you can embed semi-colons in sql *without* mysql interpreting it as a command delimiter. (I don't use php - I don't know the answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `simpleproc`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `simpleproc`(OUT param1 INT)

READS SQL DATA

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;

END $$

DELIMITER ;$$
```

Comment: ok friend. but i think as the database level it's should be works.